# Adicionar ao carrinho e quantidade no Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Tenho um site usando *woocommerce*, e preciso que não só na página de detalhe do produto apareça a opção de adicionar ao carrinho, e a quantidade, mas, que apareça nas listagens de produtos, nas categorias e etc.

Existe algum plugin pra isso, mesmo sendo pago?

Alguém já fez isso?

Answer (score 0):

Adicione esse código no functions.php do seu tema

```
add_action( 'init', 'erc_shop_archive_add_to_cart_button' );
function erc_shop_archive_add_to_cart_button() {
    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 11);
}
```

O que essa função faz é adicionar uma ação chamada woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart no evento woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item quando o hook init for iniciado.